# Tile large PDF files and adding header and footer

Tags: linux, pdf, ghostscript, tile, pdftk

for a web application running on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 which creates large custom page size PDF files with wkhtmltopdf I am looking for a solution to tile the large pdf pages into DIN paper sizes, add a header and a footer and join the single pages into one file.

At the moment my steps to produce the single file is working but very slow but it was the only running way because pdfposter only created blank pages:

1. Creation of the large pdf file with wkhtmltopdf
2. Creation of an overlay pdf with ghostscript

   ```
   exec('gs -o ' . $path . $randomValue . '.overlay.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite 
   -sFONTPATH=/usr/share/fonts/truetype -g' . $width . 'x' . $height . '
   -c '. '"/OpenSans findfont 6 scalefont setfont ' .
   '30 10 moveto (' . $footerLeft . ') show '.
   $center . ' 10 moveto (' . $footerCenter . ') dup stringwidth pop 2 div
   neg 0 rmoveto show '.
   '0 10 moveto (' . $footerRight . ') dup stringwidth pop neg ' .
   $right . ' add 0 rmoveto show ' .
   '30 ' . $top . ' moveto (' . $headerLeft . ') show ' .
   $center . ' ' . $top . ' moveto (' . $headerCenter . ') dup stringwidth
   pop 2 div neg 0 rmoveto show ' .
   '0 ' . $top . ' moveto (' . $headerRight . ') dup stringwidth pop
   neg ' . $right . ' add 0 rmoveto show"');

   e.g.
   gs -o overlay -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -sFONTPATH=/usr/share/fonts/truetype -g5950x8420 \
   -c "/OpenSans findfont 6 scalefont setfont \
   30 10 moveto (' . $footerLeft . ') show"
   ```
3. Tile the large pdf file created in step 1 into several single pdf files with ghostscript which are 60pts smaller in width and height than the paper size of the output file

   ```
   exec('gs -o ' . $path . $j . '.' . $i . '.' . $splitFile . '
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -g' . $width . 'x' .
   $height . ' -c "<</PageOffset [-' . $widthOffset . ' ' .
   $heightOffset . ']>>
   setpagedevice" -f ' . $pdfFile);

   e.g.
   gs -o outputfile.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/depress \
   -g5890x8360 -c"<</PageOffset [0 0]>> setpagedevice" -f inputfile.pdf
   ```

4 Set a new paper size according to DIN paper sizes to the single pdf pages

```
    exec('gs -o ' . $path . '1.' . $j . '.' . $i . '.' . $splitFile . '
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g' . $width . 'x' . $height . '
    -c "<</PageOffset [30 30]>> setpagedevice" -f ' . $path . $j . '.' .
    $i . '.' . $splitFile);

    e.g.
    gs -o outputfile.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g5950x8420 \
    -c "<</PageOffset [30 30]>> setpagedevice" -f inputfile.pdf
```

5. Adding the overlay created in step 2 to all single pdf pages using pdftk

   ```
   exec('pdftk '. $path . '1.' . $j . '.' . $i . '.' . $splitFile . '
   stamp ' . $path . $randomValue . '.overlay.pdf output ' . $path . '2.'
   . $j . '.' . $i . '.' . $splitFile);
   ```
6. Joining all single pdf files as pages into one pdf file using pdftk

Especially with very large pages created with wkhtmltopdf (e.g. up to 20,000pts) take a long time if the chosen output format is A4 due to the high number of pages created in step 3.

Does anyone knows a way how to skip step 4 by creating the pdf files in already with a blank border of 30pts (top, left, right, bottom)? If I could get rid of step 5 also by printing the header and footer already in step 3 (the tiling) it would save me a lot of time in creating the documents.

I already tried to print the header and footer directly on the pages while splitting but the texts are white or invisible as soon as I combine the commands.

```
    gs -o test2.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sFONTPATH=/usr/share/fonts/truetype \
    -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -g5950x8420 -c "<</PageOffset [0 0] >> \
    setpagedevice 255 0 0 setrgbcolor /OpenSans findfont 64 scalefont \
    setfont 100 100 moveto (footerline) show " -f J17ggfsh9W.data.pdf
```

I am happy for every help!

Andy

Comment: You haven't (or don't appear to have) set the colour in your 'overlay' which is almost certainly why the text is 'white', its inheriting the last colour. I've no idea what -dPDFSETTINGS=/depress is supposed to be.... I wouldn't use -dPDFSETTINSG anyway. You can certainly do steps 4 and 5 at the same time, and indeed eliminate step 2 altogether by using a BeginPage or EndPage procedure. I could probably code Ghostscript to do the whole thing in one pass, though it would mean writing a PostScript program to do it.

Comment: If I don't set a font color and run the 5 steps I get black which is fine. As soon as I set color e.g. .85 setgray or setrgbcolor the text becomes white. In the combined code above I set the color to red with 255 0 0 setrgbcolor but this has no effect.

Comment: There's really not a lot I can say, without concrete examples to work from. Note that since you are rendering the text first in your example, the content of the PDF file will be 'on top' of it (in Z-order terms). Many PDF files begin by erasing the page to white, so its entirely possible that this is where the problem lies. Again, without seeing a real file I can't really tell.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, so I will change the processing order at first step and will produce an example to post as well.